# How to print the string variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

i was using sql before but now iam using Mysql i need to know how to print the variable.

In Sql

```
 Declare @name varachar(50)
set @name ='xxxxxxx'
print  @name
```

the result will be xxxxxxx. How to get this output in mysql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display the value of a variable at the commandline in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838611/how-to-display-the-value-of-a-variable-at-the-commandline-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I think this will help you:

```
SELECT @name
```